# Why do I have to cast event.target as HTMLInputElement

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a codebase using Material Ui with some theme overrides. I'm setting up my SettingContext and SettingsProvider and I'm running into syntax I don't quite understand.

Take the following:

```
const initialState: SettingsContextProps = {
  ...defaultSettings,

  onToggleMode: () => {},
  onChangeMode: () => {},

 
  onToggleContrast: () => {},
  onChangeContrast: () => {},


  onChangeColor: () => {},


};
```

`SettingsContextProps` type is setup like this:

```
export type SettingsContextProps = {
    

  
    onToggleMode: VoidFunction;
    onChangeMode: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  

    onToggleContrast: VoidFunction;
    onChangeContrast: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  

    onChangeColor: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;


  };
```

When I'm setting up my Provider I'm attempting to understand the syntax and I'm having difficulty. Why am I using this casting `event.target as HTMLInputElement).value as ThemeMode`

```
export function SettingsProvider({ children, defaultSettings }: SettingsProviderProps) {
  const [settings, setSettings] = useState(defaultSettings);

  const onToggleMode = () => {
    setSettings({
      ...settings,
      themeMode: settings.themeMode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light',
    });
  };

  const onChangeMode = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSettings({
      ...settings,
      themeMode: (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value as ThemeMode,
    });
  };

  const onToggleContrast = () => {
    setSettings({
      ...settings,
      themeContrast: settings.themeContrast === 'default' ? 'bold' : 'default',
    });
  };

  const onChangeContrast = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSettings({
      ...settings,
      themeContrast: (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value as ThemeContrast,
    });
  };


    const onChangeColor = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setSettings({
            ...settings,    
            themeColorPresets: (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value as ThemeColorPresets,
        })
```

and finally the types they are casting as

```
  export type ThemeMode = 'light' | 'dark';
  export type ThemeContrast = 'default' | 'bold';
  export type ThemeColorPresets = 'default' | 'purple' | 'cyan' | 'blue' | 'orange' | 'red';
```

What is the line `themeColorPresets: (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value as ThemeColorPresets` doing?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you except for "TypeScript is dumb" or "TypeScript is not smart enough yet"? You can change the question to clarify what it is that you want as an answer.

Comment: The code in your question contains invalid syntax and pseudocode. When posting any code-related question (and especially ones which involve debugging), it's important that you provide a [mre]. I created a TypeScript playground using the code you provided and I fixed some the problems I described above by creating some additional types. I also commented the lines that you indicated as problems and replaced them with the same code (minus the inline assertions), and I can't reproduce the issues you described. You can view the playground [here](https://tsplay.dev/mL2yvw).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I'm still new at asking properly formatted questions. I updated the code and clarified the question at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `event.target` to `event.currentTarget`, because `target` is not always the element, that has listener